# React state is set but it looks like it's empty when rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, state

1. Make an API call from Dropbox
2. Filter the data from response and store it into an array by using map.
3. Set the array as a state
4. Use it while rendering

So this is basically what I'm trying to do - trying to make a photo gallery using Dropbox API -, and I believe I succeeded to number 3, because when I console.log the array state, it shows the contents. However, when I try to print the length of it, it shows 0 and I can't even use it while rendering - it is shown as undefined object.

I'll attach the code and the picture of dev tools. Please help me! :(

JS file

```
let dbx = new Dropbox();    

class Thumbnails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            thumbnails: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let thumbnailsArray = [];
        this.props.travel.map(file => {
            dbx.filesGetTemporaryLink({ path: file })
            .then(res => {
                thumbnailsArray.push(res.link);
            });
        });
        this.setState({ thumbnails: thumbnailsArray });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.thumbnails);
        console.log(this.state.thumbnails.length);
        console.log(this.state.thumbnails[5]);
        if (this.state.thumbnails.length < 1) {return <p>Loading...</p>}
        return(
            <table id="thumbnails">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td src={{backgroundImage: `${this.state.thumbnails[5]}`}}></td>
                        {this.state.thumbnails.map(thumbnail => {
                            return (<td style={{backgroundImage: `${thumbnail}`}}></td>);
                        })}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }


}
```

Dev tools when console.log was run

[image: Devs tools when I did console.log]

Comment: Move setState in async callback response

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue with async code. When you set state the array is empty. You could use `Promise.all` to await for all requests to finish before setting new state.

```
componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all(this.props.travel.map(file => {
        return dbx.filesGetTemporaryLink({ path: file })
          .then(res => res.link);
    })).then(thumbnailsArray => {
      this.setState({ thumbnails: thumbnailsArray });
    })
}
```